# ReactJS: Make API call with AXIOS and use in a select

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an api call and use it in a select, but my select is empty

```
const [intergrationLevel, setIntegrationLevel] = useState<any>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fectIntegrationLevel() {
      let response = await fetch('.../api/integrations');
      response = await response.json();
      setIntegrationLevel(response);
    }
    fectIntegrationLevel();
    if (isNew) {
      props.reset();
    } else {
      props.getEntity(props.match.params.id);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('intergrationLevel', intergrationLevel);
return (
//...

<div className="col-md-4">
                      <AvGroup>
                        <Label>Level</Label>
                        <AvInput
                          id="integration-level"
                          data-cy="integration-level"
                          type="select"
                          className="form-control"
                          name="realm"
                        />
                        {intergrationLevel
                          ? intergrationLevel.map(int => (
                              <option value={int.cod} key={int.cod}>
                                {int.cod}
                              </option>
                            ))
                          : null}
                      </AvGroup>
```

my console.log(integrationLevel) is at the beginning null (and it should be the problem) and then it is populated, but the select no. How can I do?

EDIT Explain:

I would to make an api call to retrieve a list of data, and use the data in a select in a form to make a request..

I have tried to make this api call, and I have use the       `setIntegrationLevel(response);` to save list in the intergrationLevel, but when I use intergrationLevel on my select, this intergrationLevel is empty ( maybe because when the return starts the api call is not ended)

EDIT2: (wrapping with select)

[image]

EDIT3:

now the situation is:

[image]

Comment: I’m having hard time to understand what is your question, can you please try to explain better so I can try to help you

Comment: @RazLuvaton yes, i have edited my post, i hoping to be more cleaer

Comment: Add your code in https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not rendering your component upon complete network call. That's why I add value in dependency array

```js
const [intergrationLevel, setIntegrationLevel] = useState<any>(null); 
async function fectIntegrationLevel() {
      let response = await fetch('.../api/integrations');
      response = await response.json();
      setIntegrationLevel(response);
    }
useEffect(() => {
    if (!intergrationLevel){
    fectIntegrationLevel();
    }
    
    if (isNew) {
      props.reset();
    } else {
      props.getEntity(props.match.params.id);
    }
  }, [intergrationLevel]);

  console.log('intergrationLevel', intergrationLevel);
return (
//...

<div className="col-md-4">
                      <AvGroup>
                        <Label>Level</Label>
                        <AvInput
                          id="integration-level"
                          data-cy="integration-level"
                          type="select"
                          className="form-control"
                          name="realm"
                        />
                        {intergrationLevel
                          ? intergrationLevel.map(int => (
                              <option value={int.cod} key={int.cod}>
                                {int.cod}
                              </option>
                            ))
                          : null}
                      </AvGroup>
```

Comment: I have tried as you suggest but now the situations is like in my edit3

Comment: What is the structure of api response exactly

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the return HTML is wrong. You are not putting anything inside the select.
try doing

```
<select>
   {array.map(int)=>(
      <option value={int.cod} key={int.cod}>
         {int.cod}
      </option>
   )}    
</select>;
```

Comment: I have tried this soluction and I only have 16 ( my data are 16 ) "arrows of the select"

Comment: I have added an image in my post

Comment: it can still be part of the form even if it's outside https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp
`    <select>
      <option >option 1 </option>
      <option > option 2 </option>
      <option >option 3 </option>
    </select>`
this should return a list with 3 options. maybe you are not rendering correctly.

Comment: @Jack23 again, are you sure you are rendering the options inside the select element? the syntax is <select><option> optionText </option></select>